# How to get the name of current category in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I need some help with my bot, wrote by discord.py.
I have async function in a bot that create a category by geting name from a command with a channel and function that must delete channel. Also this function must delete only the current channel,in which was called.
For example:
I have three categories with the channels. For example 1, 2, 3. I called command delete in the channel that replaced in 2 for example. This command will delete this channel with category and will not touch another categoris.
How do i need wtite this process. I wanted to get current name of category by position, but i understood that it will not be work.
Give me some advises or ideas, how to make this.

Some code:

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

```
@bot.command()
async def NewChannel(ctx, name):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await guild.create_category(name=name)
    cat = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
    text_channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name="text", category=cat)


@bot.command()
async def delete_current_channel(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild #How to get current category in which will send this command?
    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="current_category")
    await channel.delete()
```

I am green junior in that. So sorry for mistakes in my message and help me please. I have not got some ideas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do here, but you can get the channel category via `channel.category`

And the name of the category: `channel.category.name`

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=channel%20category#discord.abc.GuildChannel.category